# javascript : Transform not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mozilla

why doesn't this transformation occur on mozilla/ie but it does for webkit browsers using the following code?

I have tested the code below on the following browsers/version:

- Firefox: 29
- Chrome: 34
- IE: 11

**Code :**

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');

transform = "scale3d(2,2,0) " + "translate3d(20px, 0, 0) ";

$('#text').hover(function (){
    text.style.transform = transform;
    text.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    text.style.msTransform = transform;
});
```

I have based my code on this ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)) link which confirms the browser compatibility.

I created a fiddle to exemplify this issue http://jsfiddle.net/3fxf6/

Comment: At first _w3schools_  is not _w3c_.  To your problem it is probably because you set the scaling of `z`  to `0` ?

Comment: Mozilla never made it to version 29. I think you mean Firefox.

Comment: corrected thanks for the pointers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in all browsers (that support transform):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fxf6/4/)

And I made it pure JS:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text'),
    transform = "scale3d(2,2,1) translate3d(20px, 0, 0)";

text.onmouseover = function(){
    text.style.transform = transform;
    text.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    text.style.msTransform = transform;
}
```

It didn't work because you were setting the scale of `z` to `0`, making it disappear. It needs to be `1` to work on Firefox, but gives same result in all browsers.

Also you didn't need to include jQuery just to do a `hover` effect, you can just use `onmouseover` on `text` to get the same result, without having to include a bulky library.

Comment: Did you test it in FF ? In FF (at least in 29) the text disappears.

Comment: Updated for FF @t.niese

Comment: thanks for the answer guys, it surely clarified the doubts I had!